# Django REST with SPA - what structure

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django REST with SPA "within" or completely stand alone?
I'm diving into a new project where I'll try to build a SaaS web application and I've set on using Django Rest (with Postgres to utilize schemas) and React/Vue on the frontend.

What I'm unsure and what I can't seem to get an answer to is the way people structure these frameworks. E.g, on https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/ the author writes:

> I see the following patterns (which are common to almost every web
>   framework):
>
> React in its own “frontend” Django app: load a single HTML template
>   and let React manage the frontend (difficulty: medium)
>
> Django REST as a standalone API + React as a standalone SPA
>   (difficulty: hard, it involves JWT for authentication)
>
> Mix and match: mini React apps inside Django templates (difficulty:
>   simple)
>
> And here are my advices.
>
> If you’re just starting out with Django REST and React avoid the
>   option 2.
>
> Go for option number 1 (React in its own “frontend” Django app) if:
>
> - you’re building an app-like website
> - the interface has lot of user interactions/AJAX
> - you’re fine with Session based authentication
> - there are no SEO concerns
> - you’re fine with React Router

Why is this beneficial, and is it actually different from having a stand alone rest api and a standalone SPA? The reason I wanna use Django is so I don't have to worry about authentication and authorization, and I also plan on utilising the admin panel - will this "not work" if I were to use two completely standalone applications for the backend and frontend? (e.g django rest with the sole purpose of exposing the api and the frontend to consume it).

What alleged benefits do I get from having django rest and SPA in the same "root" project

Comment: Your answer is obvious in the text you quoted. It is more difficult to implement and session authentication can't work (or made to work easily) because the apps will likely be on different domains. So you will have to use more complex auth mechanisms like JWT which isn't implemented out of the box in DRF like Session auth

Comment: What makes sending a JWT in the header on each api request more difficult? Just asking

Comment: You have to first understand how the JWT scheme works. Just sending the JWT is not enough, you still have to generate and handle it in the server-side. Of course, there are libraries out there that will help you work with them but it's still earier using the inbuilt session auth than doing all that extra work. Separating the front and back is good for modularity and especially when you have separate developers working on each but the setup is more complex compared to having both in the same app.

Comment: Yeah i understand that I’ll need to handle the jwt and there are libraries to help out with that. Is this the only benefit? Also I don’t see how having the frontend and backend in  the same folder makes it any less complex?

Comment: It's not just about having them in the same code base but about hosting them on the same server. Session auth or even token auth across domains doesn't work well and could present security issues. Also, you will have to manage different server infrastructures for both probably using a Node.js server for the frontend. It's not super comnplex but definitely more complex than using one codebase and one server. If you don't find that difficult, then you should go ahead with it. Your question was why it was more complex and I think the points in the book and these comments already answered that

Comment: Okay, regarding server infrastructure, I have previously just deployed two different apps to Heroku - the rest api and the frontend and I haven't had any issues. It's been easy to be honest. All requests have a token in the request header and I haven't had problems with it, not sure about the security risks of working that way - what are they? Everyone seems to be super against JWT for sending "sensitive" data, but for cross-domain that seems to be the only solution? Is this where django shines and having the entire backend and frontend in one app - mitigating the security concerns?

Comment: It is not a security concern to use JWT to authenticate, it just implies complexity. The implication is that they are hosted on different domains or at least subdomains, so now you have to get past CORS which can be a headhache. You'll also have to implement a JWT auth backend for DRF. You can probably just install a 3rd party app to handle that for you.

Comment: Something you probably haven't considered is hot reloading. If you are building the app by having the bundle loaded into a django template, you will have to manually refresh the page to see a change. If you build out a stand-alone SPA client, you can have hot-reloading which is just awesome to work with. So you either get session auth or you get get hot reloading. I would choose hot reloading.

Comment: Keep in mind also that if you choose to separate the client during dev, you can still choose to serve the SPA by loading it into a django template when it comes time to deploy on Heroku!